# Show calendar invites that are sent to a non-gmail address but forwarded to gmail in my google calendar

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I use my google account as my main calendar. Synched on all my devices and apps. I usually receive all calendar invites there too, with all my email addresses forwarded to gmail.

Now sometimes I've started to notice that calender invites to one of my aliases don't show up anymore. Specifically the icloud privacy relay. When someone sends an email with an ICS attachment there, I see the email, I can manually add it to google calendar with a click, but it never shows up in my calendar otherwise.

This is also true for calendly appointments, if I add one of the aliases instead of gmail as my contact address. They don't show up in google calendar until I go into the email and say "add to calendar". Really frustrating.

Is there maybe a gmail addon that can solve this? Or a google account setting? I've missed a few appointments because of this

Comment: You speak of "email addresses forwarded to Gmail" and also of "aliases".  Can you explain if you are using the term interchangeably, because Gmail uses aliases in a specific and different way.

Comment: The email addresses in question are all forwarded to gmail on the receiving end. For sending, I set them up as aliases in the accounts section of the gmail settings.

Comment: That's exactly my use case. @yspreen Did you manage to find a solution yet?

Comment: @MeirCohen unfortunately no. I just got used to hitting "yes" on all invite emails I get. there's definitely potential to build a gmail app for this, or even just a third party microservice that hooks into both gmail and google cal

Comment: @yspreen And you're okay with the fact that the "yes" RSVPs are actually sent to the event participants from your main email address, and not from the one they originally invited (which is auto forwarding to your main email)? Can make a mess in some cases.

Comment: I know what you're talking about. I've found that people are familiar with this behavior and that a lot of people's calendars work like this. I would just accept imperfection here because building a real Gmail app just to fix this tiny thing is probably not worth it. It's such a niche product that building it would probably attract too small of an audience, and just for personal use it's too much work. @MeirCohen